# React sending empty form values to backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can't figure out why my form is populating my backend struct with empty strings. I can only get it to send the data correctly if I replace my onSubmit={handleSubmit} with method="POST" action="/createLink"
But even then it seems to send two form inputs.. one with empty values and one populated correctly. Backend is in Go.

```js
const Home = () => {
    //create state variables
    const [media, setMedia] = React.useState([])
    const [url, setURL] = React.useState(null)
    const [headline, setHeadline] = React.useState(null)
    const [description, setDescription] = React.useState(null)
    const [type, setType] = React.useState(null)
    const [duration, setDuration] = React.useState(null)
    const [address, setAddress] = React.useState(null)

    //HOOKS
    //get media already submitted today to display on the front end
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("/getMedia", {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type" : "application/json",
            },
        })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data)
            setMedia(...media, data);
        });
    }, []);

    //direct user back to home page
    let navigate = useNavigate()
    const handleHome = () => {
        navigate("/")
    }
    //submit media
    const handleSubmit = (e) => { 
        e.preventDefault()
        fetch("/createLink", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                url: url,
                headline: headline,
                description: description,
                type: type,
                duration: duration,
                address: address,
            }),
        })
        console.log(address, "why")
        handleHome()
    }

    //method="POST" action="/createLink"
    
    return (
        <>
          <Div>
        <H1>Submit External Media</H1>
        <form  onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
            <Field>
            <label htmlFor="url">URL Submission:</label>
            <Input type="text" id="url" name="url" required onChange={(e) => {
                setURL(e.target.value)
            }}></Input>
            </Field>
            <Field>
            <label htmlFor="headline">Headline:</label>
            <Input type="text" id="headline" name="headline" required onChange={(e) => {
                setHeadline(e.target.value)
            }}></Input>
            </Field>
            <Field>
            <label htmlFor="description">Description:</label>
            <Input type="text" id="description" name="description" required onChange={(e) => {
                setDescription(e.target.value)
            }}></Input>
            </Field>
            <Field>
            <label htmlFor="type">Type of Media:</label>
            <select id="type" name="type" onChange={(e) => {
                setType(e.target.value)
            }}>
            <option value="article" >Article</option>
            <option value="tweet" >Tweet</option>
            <option value="yt-video" >YouTube Video</option>
        </select>
        </Field>
        <Field>
            <label htmlFor="duration">Duration:</label>
            <select id="duration" name="duration" onChange={(e) => {
                setDuration(e.target.value)
            }}>
            <option value="15">15 Hours</option>
            <option value="48" >48 Hours</option>
            <option value="two-weeks" >Two Weeks</option>
        </select>
        </Field>
            <Field>
            <label htmlFor="location-lng">Street Address:</label>
            <Input type="text" id="location-lng" name="location-lng" onChange={(e) => {
                setAddress(e.target.value)
                console.log(address)
            }}></Input>
            </Field>
            <Button type="submit">SUBMIT</Button>
        </form>
        <h2>Media Submitted Today:</h2>
        { media.length >= 1 ? (
            media.map((mediaItem) => {
                const headline = mediaItem.headline
                const description = mediaItem.description
                const url = mediaItem.url
                return <Media headline={headline} description={description} url={url} />
            })
        ) : (
        <>
        <p>Looks like no external media was submitted yet today!</p>
        </>
    )}
        </Div>
        </>
    )
}
export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0):

One reason it might work with `method="POST"`, but it is not working with your javascript function is that the [default content type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-enctype) for a form is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

In `handleSubmit` it sets the type to `application/json`, which your backend may not be expecting, and is not decoding properly.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider this:

1. `console.log` everything before sending and validate input values are correct
2. The Input component seems to be Uncontrolled, validate if state if being set correctly
3. fetch is async and you're re-directing & pushing browser history state the user without waiting for the fetch call to end

Do this for advice 3:

```js
    //direct user back to home page
    let navigate = useNavigate()
    const handleHome = () => {
        navigate("/")
    }
    //submit media
    const handleSubmit = (e) => { 
        e.preventDefault()
        fetch("/createLink", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                url: url,
                headline: headline,
                description: description,
                type: type,
                duration: duration,
                address: address,
            }),
        }).then(() => handleHome()) // We are sure data was sent

    }
```

Do this for advice 1:

```js
    //direct user back to home page
    let navigate = useNavigate()
    const handleHome = () => {
        navigate("/")
    }
    //submit media
    const handleSubmit = (e) => { 
        e.preventDefault()
        const data = {
          url,
          headline,
          description,
          type,
          duration,
          address,
        }
        console.log({ data }) // Check the dev console
        // JS Enhanced Object literals.
        // https://www.sitepoint.com/es6-enhanced-object-literals
        fetch("/createLink", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
        }).then(() => handleHome()) // We are sure data was sent

    }
```